# Git post-receive [[ not found

Tags: git, sh, githooks, git-post-receive

I have a git hook (`post-receive`), that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/vservices
while read OLDSHA NEWSHA REF ; do
    if [[ "$NEWSHA" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]]; then
        git --git-dir=/home/vservices/.git --work-tree=/home/vservices fetch -p origin
    else
        git --git-dir=/home/vservices/.git --work-tree=/home/vservices pull
    fi
done
```

And I am getting this error message when I run `git push dev :test2`:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: 10: [[: not found
remote: Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'test2'
remote: from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

I don't know much about `sh`, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[[ … ]]` isn’t POSIX-shell-compatible; you probably want `bash` or something similar.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: @ryan-naddy, most probably the system on which you experience this problem is some sort of Debian or its derivative as they have [`dash`](http://packages.debian.org/dash) as their `/bin/sh` by default -- a fast and lightweight POSIX-compliant shell intended to run scripts (as opposed to `bash` which is targeted to be used interactively). Read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) for more info.

Comment: For portability, change the command instead of the shebang: `if [ "$NEWSHA" = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then`.